# Microsoft Flow To Update Items With ID Above 5000 In A SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I have an issue with an update automation I created with Microsoft Flow that I can't figure out how to fix. I have two SharePoint lists in different site collections. I've set up a flow when an item is created in the first list to copy it to another SP list, then when that very same item is modified in the second list, to update the same item in the first list. Both are linked with each other based on the ID of the item created in the first list. Basically I have a field in the second list that takes the value of the ID of the item from the first list. And then when that entry is modified in the second list it compares the two values and if they match, it updates the same item in the first list. I made all that work to a test list that I created and it is working fine, but then when I tried to move the automation to an identical list having an ID of 15600+, it just does not want to update the item in the first list when modified in the second list. And what is interesting is that microsoft flow shows all actions of the flow as successful, but yet it doesn't update the item in the first list. The list has an ID of more than 15600, but the actual items inside are about 3000. Is it because of the ID and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, managed to make it work. What I did is instead of Get Items, I used the Get Item action, removed the filtering action and input that into the Get Item action itself, to compare the ID of the item in the first list with the copied item in the second list and based on that to update.